# Relationship between table and parent div

Tags: html, css

So I have a table inside of a div and I have not specified any width. For tables with lots of content, the table width seems exceed the width of the parent div. Why is that occurring? How do I make it so that the table width is always some percentage of the parent div?

Comment: Is your div declared as a float?

Comment: I suggest giving more information on what you have already tried and, for example, sketches of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You might be asking the wrong question unknowingly and the more info you can provide, the better the answers you'll receive.

Answer (score 0):

Set a percentage width for the table, and make sure your CSS hasn't declared a width for div elsewhere. Double check your HTML to make sure you properly nested the table and closed your div tag. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Whatever</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <table><!--all your table stuffs--></table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  width: 90%;
}

table {
  width: 90%;
}
```

Classes are a better way to address this, but the above code will make sure your div is 90% of the page width, and the table is 90% of your div width (allowing for margins, padding, etc).

Comment: The above code won't work if the content of the contained elements doesn't break (eg long lines of contiguous text, big images etc). You need to set `table-layout` which is `auto` by default.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is your friend.

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
```

This will ensure the table element has the final say in the width rather than the content.

Obligatory spoon-feeding example:

```
<style>
#sampleTable { 
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:80%;

    background-color:#99F;
 }

#container { 
    width:500px;

    background-color:#F99;
 }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <table id="sampleTable">
        <tr><td>Exampleofreallylongtextwhichshouldbreaklayoutnormally</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In that example the table should always be 400 pixels (80% of the parent's 500px). Typical caveats for padding, margins etc still apply.

You might also want to consider `word-wrap` and `overflow` for determining what to do with the content which would normally push out the size of the table.

Comment: and inline CSS is your enemy ;)

Comment: It's a quick example for a quick question.